# Do Brunei Darussalam passport holders require transit visa in Brussels?

Tags: visas, schengen, transit

A colleague with Brunei Darussalam passport is flying from Delhi to Manchester and will transit in Brussels fro a few hours?
Does he need a transit visa in Brussels?